# Series with multiple objects in JSON file in Amcharts

Tags: amcharts

I'm trying to create 2 series for my chart in amcharts. I have the following JSON:

```
[
{"equipament":"pir1","watts":48.0,"currentdate":"2020-02-06T21:11:55"},
{"equipament":"pir2","watts":16.0,"currentdate":"2020-02-06T21:11:55"},
{"equipament":"pir1","watts":3.0,"currentdate":"2020-02-06T21:16:52"},
{"equipament":"pir2","watts":12.0,"currentdate":"2020-02-06T21:16:52"}
]
```

I need to create a graph where on my X axis will be the currentdate field, and on the Y axis will be the watts field, but I need to take into account the equipament field.

I'm using typescript + angular in my development. What I managed to do:

```
 let chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

  chart.data = [
{"equipament":"pir1","watts":48.0,"currentdate":"2020-02-06T21:11:55"},
{"equipament":"pir2","watts":16.0,"currentdate":"2020-02-06T21:11:55"},
{"equipament":"pir1","watts":3.0,"currentdate":"2020-02-06T21:16:52"},
{"equipament":"pir2","watts":12.0,"currentdate":"2020-02-06T21:16:52"}
  ];

  chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";

  // Create axes
  let dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
  dateAxis.tooltipDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";

  let valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

  // Create series PIR1
  let series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
  series.dataFields.valueY = "watts";
  series.dataFields.dateX = "currentdate";
  series.tooltipText = "{equipament}: [bold]{watts}[/]"
  series.name = "pir1";

  // Create series PIR2
  let series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
  series2.dataFields.valueY = "watts";
  series2.dataFields.dateX = "currentdate";
  series2.tooltipText = "{equipament}: [bold]{watts}[/]"
  series2.name = "pir2";

  chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
  chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;
  chart.cursor.lineY.disabled = true;
  valueAxis.cursorTooltipEnabled = false;
  chart.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();

  chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();

  this.chart = chart;
```

However, when checking the graph, the series are overlapping. I believe I have to add some code to link to the equipament field. I already searched the amcharts documentation, but I didn't find anything about it. I appreciate that I can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

amCharts can't filter out data for each series by specific key/value.

The easiest way is to assign data to each series individually:

```
series.data = [
  {"equipament":"pir1","watts":48.0,"currentdate":"2020-02-06T21:11:55"},
  {"equipament":"pir1","watts":3.0,"currentdate":"2020-02-06T21:16:52"}
];

series2.data =  [
  {"equipament":"pir2","watts":16.0,"currentdate":"2020-02-06T21:11:55"},
  {"equipament":"pir2","watts":12.0,"currentdate":"2020-02-06T21:16:52"}
];
```

This way you don't have to set `chart.data` at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll think of some way to dynamically separate Json's objects.

Comment: I am having trouble exporting data doing this way. I used the following code:
       series.exporting.menu = new am4core.ExportMenu ();
       series.exporting.menu.align = "right";
       series.exporting.menu.verticalAlign = "bottom";
However, it does not export data from serie2.

Comment: I managed to solve
 the export problem following this tutorial: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/combining-local-data-from-multiple-series-for-export/